# How robust is the Project Silk type architecture for data heavy LOB apps?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architectural-patterns, rich-client-platform

[Project Silk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh396380.aspx) looks good for social networking applications where there are streams of frequently updated data that need to appear in a dashboard style presentation.

I would like to ask if such an architecture also is appropriate for typical LOB apps that are data-heavy. Currently, we use WPF or Silverlight for rich client presentation (tabs of master/detail forms, Office Ribbon styles, drag and drop, grids, charts). Project Silk seems to open up another option for such apps.

A few questions I have:

- Are the technologies used in this stack mature enough for consideration for enterprise use?
- Is the breadth of current and upcoming JQuery UI widgets enough to cover these needs?
- Will this architecture be performant running in interpreted mode on a browser instead of fully utilizing CPU power as native apps do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the technologies used in this stack mature enough for consideration for enterprise use?

jQuery, asp.net mvc 3, html 5, css 3 are mature and works ok for enterprise use.
There are some differences depending on the browser used. This is a big issue.

> Is the breadth of current and upcoming JQuery UI widgets enough to cover these needs?

No. 
Silverlight/wpf is much more "stable". The UI box model is excellent.
Silverlight/wpf is also more "solid" as it is compiled and can be fully tested.

> Will this architecture be performant running in interpreted mode on a browser instead of fully utilizing CPU power as native apps do?

It will be performant, but not as performant as a native app or a silverlight/wpf app which is compiled on the customer's computer.